# Matrix derivative in images matching problem

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, procrustes-problem

### Problem

Suppose zero-centered matrices $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ of shape $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$. Each row of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ represents a point on 2-D plane. Therefore, they each represent a shape on the 2-D plane.

If we want to match $\mathbf{X}$ by transforming $\mathbf{Y}$ with scaling factor $\beta$ and rotation $\mathbf{O}\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, i.e.
$$
\min_{\beta, \mathbf{O}} \Vert \mathbf{X}-\beta \mathbf{YO}\Vert_F^2
$$
Derive optimal $\beta$ and $O$.

### What I Have Done

This seems to be a pretty easy question, since
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(\beta,\mathbf{O})
&:= \Vert \mathbf{X}-\beta \mathbf{YO}\Vert_F^2\\
&=tr(\mathbf{XX}^T)-2\beta tr(\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{XO}^T)+\beta^2 tr(\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{OO}^T)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then by following formula
$$
\nabla_\mathbf{X}tr(\mathbf{AX}^T)=\mathbf{A}\\
\nabla_\mathbf{X}tr(\mathbf{BXX}^T)=\mathbf{BX}+\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{X}
$$
I have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_\mathbf{O}f(\beta,\mathbf{O})
&=-2\beta\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{X}+2\beta^2\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{YO}\\
\nabla_\beta f(\beta,\mathbf{O})
&=-2tr(\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{XO}^T)+2\beta tr(\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{OO}^T)
\end{aligned}
$$
However, setting two equations to 0 does not seem to result in something  solvable.

Could someone help me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimal $\beta$ and $O$ are
$$\beta_* = \pm\frac{\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)}{\|Y\|_F^2}\,,\quad
  O_*=\operatorname{sign}(\beta)UV^T\,,$$
where $Y^TX=U\Sigma V^T$ is the SVD of the matrix $Y^TX$ and 
$$\operatorname{sign}(x)=\begin{cases}\hphantom{-}1\,,\quad x\geq 0\\-1\,,\quad x<0\end{cases}\,.$$

To show that, let $\beta$ and $O$ be arbitrary.
We have
$$f(\beta,O) \geq \min_\hat{O} \|X-(\beta Y)\hat{O}\|_F^2\,.$$
The right hand side is Orthogonal Procrustes problem with solution 
$$\hat{O}=\operatorname{sign}(\beta)UV^T = \operatorname{sign}(\beta)Q_*\,,$$
because $(\beta Y)^TX = (\operatorname{sign}(\beta)U)(|\beta|\Sigma)V^T$ is the SVD of matrix $(\beta Y)^TX$.
Therefore,
\begin{align}
f(\beta,O)&\geq f(\beta, \operatorname{sign}(\beta)O_*)\\
  &= \|X\|_F^2-2\beta\operatorname{tr}(Y^TX\operatorname{sign}(\beta)O_*^T)+\beta^2\|Y\|_F^2\\
  &= \|X\|_F^2-2|\beta|\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma) + \beta^2\|Y\|_F^2\\
  &\geq f(\beta_*, O_*) \,.
\end{align}
The last inequality holds because quadratic polynomial in $|\beta|$ attains its minimum for $|\beta|=|\beta_*|$ with value of minimum being $f(\beta_*, O_*) = f(-\beta_*,-O_*)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we know the optimal $\beta$ and use it to define the matrix $C=\beta Y.\,\,$ Let's also assume that we have calculated the SVD of $Y^TX$ 
$$\eqalign{
&Y^TX &= US_yV^T \,\,\,\implies C^TX &= U(\beta S_y)V^T = US_cV^T \\
}$$
The problem can now be re-cast in the form of the standard [Orthogonal Procrustes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) problem, whose solution can be expressed in terms of this singular value decompostion.
$$\eqalign{
&\min_O \|X-&CO\|_F \,\,\,\implies O = UV^T \\
}$$
**NB:**   The optimal $O$ is independent of $\beta$.

Given this optimal $O$, the optimal $\beta$ is obtained by solving a much easier problem.
$$
\min_\beta\|X-\beta\,YO\|_F^2 \,\,\,\implies
\beta=\frac{{\rm tr}\big(X^TYO\big)}{{\rm tr}\big((YO)^TYO\big)}
=\frac{{\rm tr}(S_y)}{{\rm tr}(Y^TY)}
$$

Comment: How can you tell that $\beta = \|X\|_F/\|Y\|_F$ is the optimal $\beta$?